# Can't get gmp compiler flag to work

Tags: c++, gmp

I've written some code that compares 16 bit decimal calculations, with "infinite precision" FP calculations using GMP. I've unzipped, untarred, etc. the gmp library into the folder with my source code in it. However, upon trying to compile in the terminal, I get an error: 
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm compiling using: g++ FinalBench.cc -lgmpxx -lgmp
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you `locate` "libgmp" is it actually residing somewhere in your compiler invocations link path? Is it present at all? Is "libgmp" the actual name of the lib you need to link against?

Comment: Yes, the two libraries are present in the folder I am currently in and are called libgmp.la and libgmpxx.la

Comment: Did you add the current folder to the link path? I.e. `g++ ... -L${currentPath} ...` ?

Comment: On trying to do this, I'm getting an argument to -L is missing when I try to use currentPath, and a bad substitution error when I try to put the actual path to my current directory in.

Comment: libgmp.la is for libtool. g++ (ld in fact) wants libgmp.so or libgmp.a. Also, dumping the sources of a library into your code is a weird thing to do, you are supposed to configure-make-make install the library then get rid of the sources.